# Anchor links are generating (almost) empty page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a one page design and so I want my Nav-bar items to link to the relevant sections of the page. If I type the links that output to the browser manually they work fine, but when clicking on the links they generate an empty page (except for a javascript script that is in the footer.

Tried using different rails helpers and also tried using plain old HTML. Same problem happens when I click the links

This is the link in: /layouts/_navbar.html.erb

```html
<li class="nav-item"><%= link_to "Menus", root_path(anchor: "menus"), class: 'nav-link' %></li>
```

This is the target in /pages/home.html.erb

```html
<section class="site-section" id="menus">
```

Expected result is for address to show : 'localhost:3000/#menus'
and for the page to move to menus section
Actual result is the same address but the page is blank apart from text : '2019' (generated from a javscript in the footer)

If I manually type 'localhost:3000/#menus' it works fine!

Comment: This sounds like something Turbolinks would interfere with. Are you using Turbolinks?

Comment: @JoshBrody Yes you are right. I just found a solution after much frustration... I had to add data: { turbolinks: false } to every link on the page. I even have to add it to this: <%= link_to 'Home', root_path %>  ... What is the reason for this and is there a better way to fix the issue?

Answer (score 0):

Turbolinks was causing the issue, which I obviously need to read up on.

Updated my link_to's like so:

```
<%= link_to "Eat", root_path(anchor: "menus"), data: { turbolinks: false }, class: 'nav-link' %>
```

Answer (score 0):

I was tearing my hair out with this problem too; any page I navigated to using Turbolinks just rendered "2020" (i.e. the current year) in plan text with nothing else on the page.

It turns out that the bootstrap template I'd used in my project included this in the footer HTML:

```html
<footer>
  ...
  Copyright &copy;<script>document.write(new Date().getFullYear());</script>
  ...
</footer>
```

... of course the issue was:

```js
document.write(new Date().getFullYear());
```

... so I just changed it to:

```html
<footer>
  ...
  Copyright &copy;<%= Date.current.year %>
  ...
</footer>
```